# I am trying to make a hovering dropdown menu, however, the button is not properly positioned

Tags: html, css

I have a header container and not all the contents of it are being correctly distributed, some appear at top 0% and left 0% while others appear at like top 50% and left 50% here's the CSS container and the html code:

```css
.main_body_container{
    width:100%;
    height:2000px;
    background-size:cover;
    position:relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin:0;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

.background{
    width:100%;
    height:1080px;
    background:url("../images/background.jpg");
    background-size:cover;
    position:fixed;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:0;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

.header_container{
    width:100%;
    height:20%;
    position:fixed;
    display:flex;
    align-items:start;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,rgb(104, 15, 107),rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
    opacity:1;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:0;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

.header_icon{
    width:77px;
    height:90px;
    background: url("../images/samurai.png");
    background-size:contain;
    position:relative;
    top:10%;
    left:5%
}

.header_txt_frame{
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    position:relative;
    top:30%;
    left:6%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Cyberpunk';
    src: url("../font/Cyberpunk.otf") format('opentype'),url("../font/Cyberpunk.ttf") format('truetype');

}
@font-face{
    font-family:'Blender';
    src:url("../font/Blender-Pro-Book.otf") format('opentype')
}
.header_text{
    color:#fcee0a;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    animation: glitch-animation 2s infinite;
    font-family:'Cyberpunk',sans-serif;
    font-size:40px;
}

.glitch::before,
.glitch::after {
    content: attr(data-text);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.glitch::before {
    animation: glitch-animation-before 3s infinite;
}

.glitch::after {
    animation: glitch-animation-after 2s infinite;
}

@keyframes glitch-animation {
    0% {
        transform: translate(0);
    }
    20% {
        transform: translate(-2px, -2px);
    }
    40% {
        transform: translate(2px, 2px);
    }
    60% {
        transform: translate(-2px, 2px);
    }
    80% {
        transform: translate(2px, -2px);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translate(0);
    }
}

@keyframes glitch-animation-before {
    0%, 100% {
        clip: rect(5px, 999px, 28px, 0);
        transform: skew(0deg);
    }
    20% {
        clip: rect(14px, 999px, 5px, 0);
        transform: skew(3deg);
    }
    40% {
        clip: rect(8px, 999px, 6px, 0);
        transform: skew(-3deg);
    }
    60% {
        clip: rect(15px, 999px, 28px, 0);
        transform: skew(0deg);
    }
    80% {
        clip: rect(18px, 999px, 8px, 0);
        transform: skew(3deg);
    }
}

@keyframes glitch-animation-after {
    0%, 100% {
        clip: rect(13px, 999px, 28px, 0);
        transform: skew(0deg);
    }
    20% {
        clip: rect(18px, 999px, 8px, 0);
        transform: skew(-3deg);
    }
    40% {
        clip: rect(5px, 999px, 28px, 0);
        transform: skew(0deg);
    }
    60% {
        clip: rect(14px, 999px, 5px, 0);
        transform: skew(3deg);
    }
    80% {
        clip: rect(8px, 999px, 6px, 0);
        transform: skew(-3deg);
    }
}

.body_text_container{
    width: 100%;
    height:1400px;
    position:relative;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    opacity:.7;
    top: 0%;
    left:0%;
}

.header_menu_container{
    width:40%;
    height:100%;
    position:relative;
    left:40%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    align-items: center;
    display:flex;
}

.menu_list{
    align-items:center;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    border:1px solid #fcee0a;
    display:flex;
    height:48px;
    width:100%;
    top:50%;
    margin:0;
}

.menu_item{
    align-items:center;
    color:#fff;
    font-family: 'Blender',sans-serif;
    font-size:22px;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:flex;
    width:25%;
    height:100%;
}

.menu-sub-list{
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    backdrop-filter: blur(8px);
    background:rgba(150, 118, 118, 0.6);
    position:relative;
    left:0;
    top:0%;
    display:none;
}

.menu_item:hover .menu-sub-list{display:block;}
.menu_item:hover{background-color:#fcee0a; color:black;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="icon" href="./images/fav.jpg">
    <link href="./css/index_main.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Coffe</title>
</head>
<body style="margin:0">
    <div class="main_body_container">
        <div class="background"></div>
        <div class="body_text_container"></div>
        <div class="header_container">
            <div class="header_icon"></div>
            <div class="header_txt_frame">
                <span class="header_text">Humanisick</span>
            </div>
            <div class="header_menu_container">
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>      
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, these are the items that are appearing properly:

```
.header_icon{
    width:77px;
    height:90px;
    background: url("../images/samurai.png");
    background-size:contain;
    position:relative;
    top:10%;
    left:5%
}

.header_txt_frame{
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    position:relative;
    top:30%;
    left:6%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

And this one is not:

```
.dropdown{
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    top:0%;
    left:0;
}
```

I'd like that all the items appeared at top and left 0% and then I would be able to properly move them on the header container, I would like something similar to what is on this website: https://www.cyberpunk.net/us/es/

Answer (score 0):

In your css code I can see In this class **".header_txt_frame"**

You have applied

```
  .header_txt_frame{
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    position:relative;
    top:30%;
    left:6%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

There is a problem here Because as you said you don't want
any top or left

You can just change it to

```
  .header_txt_frame{
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    position:relative;
    top:0%;
    left:0%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

And then it will be at their original position.

Comment: Sorry for the confussion, those elements are already on the positions where I want them to be display, however, the .dropdown is not appearing at the original position even though the position i set there was top 0 and left 0

Comment: Ok then You can Just make the display of that to block if the dropdown is not in the navbar, if it is then just remove the display attribute entirely

Comment: and is this the whole css code? because you have nested dropdown in many things so it could also be the reason so share the whole css code.

Comment: Alright, I just shared the css code completely, I made some changes and it is working better now, however, I'd like to ask, why does it seem like the text takes a part of space and moves the other components to the side of the text? can't I just place a component on top of the text?

Comment: what are you doing share the css part in the css section not in html so that I can run the script and see what is wrong.